# How to provide Mock server host while initialising FirebaseMessaging instance in Java SDK

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

While initializing the FirebaseMessaging instance, I want to provide a mock server host that I'll be using from Functional tests/SLTs.

After check all the parameters it takes, I do not see any option to provide the host.

The code looks like this:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.*;

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/jsonFilePath");
    InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
    return FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(input))
            .build();
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getFirebaseOptions(),
            "project-name");
this.firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);
```

Here, in FirebaseOptions as well there is no member that represents the host.

I need some help here, if setting up a mock server host not possible in how to write Service level tests or functional tests?